# Show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{x^4-2x+1}{x-1} + \sqrt{x} =3$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, self-learning

> Show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{x^4-2x+1}{x-1} + \sqrt{x} =3$ from the definition (using $\epsilon-\delta$)

Why can't I do something like this?

We want:

$|\frac{x^4-2x+1}{x-1} + \sqrt{x}-3| = |\frac{x^4-2x+1}{x-1} + \frac{x-9}{\sqrt{x}+3}| \le |\frac{x^4-2x+1}{x-1}| + |\frac{x-9}{\sqrt{x}+3}| \le |x^3+x^2+x-1| + |x-9| \le |x|^3 + |x|^2+|x-1| + |x-9| < \epsilon$

Now suppose $|x-1| < 1$, then $|x|\le 2$ and $|x-9| \le 9$, so

$$|x|^3 + |x|^2+|x-1| + |x-9| < 2^3+2^2+9+|x-1| < \epsilon$$

Now take $\delta = \min\{1, \epsilon -21\}$.

But this clearly is wrong because $\delta$ needs to be positive for every $\epsilon>0$, what part of my working is incorrect? (I know how to get the answer properly, just wondering why this way is incorrect, I'm quite new to $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You went off the track when you introduced the term
$$\left|\frac{x-9}{\sqrt x+3}\right|\ .$$
As $x\to1$, this term will tend to $2$ and therefore it can't be made arbitrarily small.  Something like
$$\eqalign{\left|\frac{x^4-2x+1}{x-1}+\sqrt{x}-3\right|
  &\le\left|\frac{x^4-2x+1}{x-1}-2\right|+\left|\sqrt{x}-1\right|\cr
  &=\left|x-1\right|\left|x^2+2x+3\right|+\left|\frac{x-1}{\sqrt x+1}\right|\cr}$$
would have a better chance of working.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. So in a general sense, when doing e-d proofs, the idea is to get the 'thing' inside the modulus, $|**|< \epsilon$, as small as possible as $x$ approaches $c$? Which means if I were to introduce any "plus" terms, they need to be able to become arbitrarily small (as $x \rightarrow c$), hence your motivation to include $+|\sqrt{x}-1|$?

Comment: That sounds like a good summary of the necessary ideas.  The thing is that there is a bit of tension between making the estimate a little bigger in order to simplify the algebra, and making it too much bigger so that the proof is wrecked.  This is why this kind of question is probably more of an art than a science ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: This answer was posted before the condition of using the definition with $(\epsilon-\delta)$ was specified.

Factorize $x^4-2x+1$, to remove the singularity in the denominator:
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^4-2x+1}{x-1} + \sqrt{x} & = \lim_{x\to1}\frac{(x-1)(x^3+x^2+x-1)}{x-1} + \sqrt{x} = \\
 & = \lim_{x\to1}(x^3+x^2+x-1)  + \sqrt{x} = \\
 & =  3
\end{aligned}

Comment: Similar to the post above this does not answer the OPs direct question, he's interested in proving the limit by the definition, not by using limit theorems.

Comment: He added this condition after our answers.

Comment: @DanZimm best not to say "the post above" as the order of posts is not fixed.  Better to identify it by name.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize there was an edit, my apologies. A heads up for you nonetheless

Comment: @David good point, I meant Rainer's post

Comment: Thanks @DanZimm. What is the general rule of thumb when the original poster makes a late edit which deprecates an answer?

Comment: No idea, @David might know (he's more senior on MSE :D)

Comment: @DanZimm not all that senior... but what I would probably do is edit my post to make it clear that I was answering a previous version of the OP.  Might be worth asking for people's opinions on [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you. If you are interested in this discussion, it can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/15073/157639).